# Applying a function to two pandas DataFrames efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DatetimeIndexed DataFrames with identical indexes and column names. and approximately 8.26 million rows and 44 columns each, the DataFrames are joined then groupby is applied using a 10 minute time interval giving approximately 6884 groups. The matching column pairs are then iterated over, a single value is returned for each group and column pair.

The solution below works and takes 34 mins on a Xeon E5-2697 v3 and all the DataFrames can fit in memory.

I reckon there should be a more efficient way of computing this with two DataFrames, perhaps using Dask?

Although it is not clear to me how to do the time based groupby for a Dask DataFrame.

```
def circular_mean(burst_veldirection, burst_velspeed):
    x = y = 0.
    for angle, weight in zip(burst_veldirection.values, burst_velspeed.values):
        x += math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * weight
        y += math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * weight

    mean = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
    if mean < 0:
        mean = 360 + mean
    return mean

def circ_mean(df):
    results = []
    for x in range(0,45):
        results.append(circular_mean(df[str(x)], df[str(x) + 'velspeed']))
    return results

burst_veldirection_velspeed = burst_veldirection.join(burst_velspeed, rsuffix='velspeed')

result = burst_veldirection_velspeed.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min')).apply(circ_mean)
```

[Example short HDF file containing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7NIHgZWSJnKNjBIMFZmcl9tNTg/view?usp=sharing) the first 10,000 records covering 23 minutes

Comment: At 8 million rows, this project may be small enough to not need Dask, as @EFT pointed out. If you are to use Dask, you can utilize Dask to perform the merge by converting one dataframe to a a Dask dataframe and then using `dask.dataframe.merge` to merge the Dask dataframe with the vanilla Pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't get you away from `groupby`, but just shifting over to numpy functions from doing everything element-wise gets a roughly 8-fold speed boost for me.

```
def circ_mean2(df):
    df2 = df.iloc[:, 45:].copy()
    df1 = df.iloc[:, :45].copy()
    x = np.sum(np.cos(np.radians(df1.values))*df2.values, axis=0)
    y = np.sum(np.sin(np.radians(df1.values))*df2.values, axis=0)
    arctan = np.degrees(np.arctan2(y, x))
    return np.where(arctan>0, arctan, arctan+360).tolist()
```

Comparison on 100 rows (random data):

```
burst_veldirection_velspeed.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min')).apply(circ_mean)
Out[546]: 
    2017-01-01 00:00:00    [107.1417250368678, 256.8946560151866, 213.146...
    2017-01-01 00:10:00    [26.33395947005812, 27.786466256197127, 94.898...
    2017-01-01 00:20:00    [212.56183600787307, 284.77924347375733, 241.7...
    2017-01-01 00:30:00    [302.1659401891579, 91.1768853178421, 194.9664...
    2017-01-01 00:40:00    [90.29680187822757, 337.4345622590224, 302.219...
    2017-01-01 00:50:00    [94.88722975883893, 319.5580499260627, 204.511...
    2017-01-01 01:00:00    [133.4980653288851, 55.16669017531442, 20.7527...
    2017-01-01 01:10:00    [356.67045637546113, 151.25258425458003, 200.1...
    2017-01-01 01:20:00    [350.2489907863962, 33.284286840600046, 145.66...
    2017-01-01 01:30:00    [135.74199444105565, 62.66259615135012, 257.80...
    Freq: 10T, dtype: object

burst_veldirection_velspeed.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min')).apply(circ_mean2)
Out[547]: 
    2017-01-01 00:00:00    [107.1417236328125, 256.8946533203125, 213.146...
    2017-01-01 00:10:00    [26.333953857421875, 27.78646469116211, 94.898...
    2017-01-01 00:20:00    [212.5618438720703, 284.77923583984375, 241.72...
    2017-01-01 00:30:00    [302.16595458984375, 91.1768798828125, 194.966...
    2017-01-01 00:40:00    [90.29680633544922, 337.4345703125, 302.219909...
    2017-01-01 00:50:00    [94.88722229003906, 319.55804443359375, 204.51...
    2017-01-01 01:00:00    [133.498046875, 55.166690826416016, 20.7527561...
    2017-01-01 01:10:00    [356.6704406738281, 151.25257873535156, 200.13...
    2017-01-01 01:20:00    [350.2489929199219, 33.2842903137207, 145.6609...
    2017-01-01 01:30:00    [135.7419891357422, 62.66258239746094, 257.807...
    Freq: 10T, dtype: object


%timeit burst_veldirection_velspeed.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min')).apply(circ_mean)
10 loops, best of 3: 80.3 ms per loop

%timeit burst_veldirection_velspeed.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min')).apply(circ_mean2)
10 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop
```

On 10,000:

```
%timeit burst_veldirection_velspeed.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min')).apply(circ_mean) 
1 loop, best of 3: 6.65 s per loop

%timeit burst_veldirection_velspeed.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min')).apply(circ_mean2)
1 loop, best of 3: 709 ms per loop
```